# Python selenium crawling

Tags: python, selenium

Here is code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=比特币&ie=utf-8&tab=good')

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.j_th_tit')[0].click()

a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.d_post_content.j_d_post_content.clearfix')
for i in a:
    print(i.text)
```

Here is HTML I'm struggling with. There are many texts at the page, but those all have same class; *d_post_content j_d_post_content  clearfix*.

```
<div id='post_content_52497574149' class='d_post_content j_d_post_content  clearfix' style='display:;'> Here is the Text that I need to get; it is written in Chinese and stackoverflow may not permit to writhe Chinese in the body </div>
```

I want to automatically access to the website and get some texts for my homework assignment. With this code above, I could open the website, click the link, but I cannot access to the text needed. All of the texts needed are in the class, so I tried to access to the Class to get the texts, but it didn't work. When I check the length of the list **a**, len(a) is zero. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This line bring you to a new tab:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.j_th_tit')[0].click()
```

So you need switch it first. After perform the above, just add a line:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link in this statement:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.j_th_tit')[0].click()
```

A new tab is opened. But you are not switching to that tab.

I would recommend adding this statement:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Before you actually call `find_elements_by_css_selector`.

It will solve your issue.